# i am checking if username exist in database and then sending response code 200/400

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

users.js

```
import express from 'express'
import Validator from 'validator'
import isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty'
import isEmail from 'validator/lib/isEmail';
import {MongoClient} from 'mongodb'

let router = express.Router()

function validatInput(data){
    var error = {}

    if(data.username === ""){
        error.email = "this field is req"
    }

    if(!isEmail(data.username)){
        error.email = "email is not valid "
    }

    if(data.password === ""){
        error.password = "this field is req"
    }

    return{
        error:error,
        isValid:isEmpty(error)
    }
}

router.post('/',(reqs,resP)=>{
    var url ="mongodb://localhost:27017/loginUsers"

    const {error,isValid} = validatInput(reqs.body)
    error.email = err
    console.log(error.email +"body")

    if(!isValid ){
        console.log("not valid")
        resP.status(400).send(error)
    }

    let err=""
    MongoClient.connect(url,function (err,db) {
        if(err){
            console.log("database connection error")
        }
        else{
            var collection = db.collection('UsersList')

            var student = reqs.body
            console.log(" email "+ reqs.body.username)
            collection.find({"username":reqs.body.username},function(err,res){

                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                }
                else if(!res){
                    err=null
                    console.log(" not find" )
                    collection.insert([student],function(err,res){
                        if(err){
                            console.log("data not inserted")
                        }else{
                            console.log(res)
                        }
                    })
                    resP.status("success")
                }
                else{
                    console.log("usere present")
                    error.email = "email is not valid "
                   resP.status(400).send(error)
                }
            })
        }
    })
})

export default router
```

it first check if data in field is valid or not and then check if data base have same username or not 
it is success when field are correct/incorrect 
but when i verify database (due to asynchronous behaviour ) it do not wait. and goes to server.js and send 200 status always 
i check network in chrome and their it show pending status of users.js

so how to solve this problem 
so that after checking in mongodb i can send data only

index.js

```
import express from 'express';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';
import config from '../webpack.config.dev';
import open from 'open';
import bodyparser from 'body-parser'

import users from './routes/users'
/* eslint-disable no-console */

const port = 3000;
const app = express();
const compiler = webpack(config);

app.use(bodyparser.json())

app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
  noInfo: true,
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}));

app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));

app.use('/api/users',users)

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  console.log("i am sending file")
  res.sendFile(path.join( __dirname, '../src/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    open(`http://localhost:${port}`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Why you tagged javascript in your question?

Comment: "StackOverFlow" suggested me.

Comment: okkay thanku, I got the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try maybe improving the flow of your code using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and the [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) keyword (you issue is tough to see due to the callback nature of your code).

Let me know if this works

```
import express from 'express'
import Validator from 'validator'
import isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty'
import isEmail from 'validator/lib/isEmail';
import {MongoClient} from 'mongodb'

let router = express.Router()

function validatInput(data){
    var error = {}

    if(data.username === ""){
        error.email = "this field is req"
    }

    if(!isEmail(data.username)){
        error.email = "email is not valid "
    }

    if(data.password === ""){
        error.password = "this field is req"
    }

    return {
        error: error,
        isValid: isEmpty(error)
    }
}

router.post('/',async function (reqs,resP) {
    var url ="mongodb://localhost:27017/loginUsers"

    const { error, isValid } = validatInput(reqs.body)
    error.email = err
    console.log(error.email +"body")

    if(!isValid ){
        console.log("not valid")
        resP.status(400).send(error)
    }else{
        try{
            const db = await MongoClient.connect(url);
            const collection = db.collection('UsersList')
            const student = reqs.body
            console.log(" email "+ reqs.body.username)

            const dbUser = await collection.find({"username":reqs.body.username});

            if(!dbUser){
                console.log("User Not Found" )
                await collection.insert([student]);
                resP.status("success")
            }else{
                console.log("usere present")
                error.email = "email is not valid "
                resP.status(400).send(error)
            }
        }catch(e){
            console.log("database connection error")
            resP.status(500).send(error)
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: thanku for you response sir. this code is good, but know i have use some other approach . thanku

Comment: @Rajan in general using promises or async is cleaner and makes it more obvious when things fail